# Why is it so hard to let go of our insecurities?

Tags: social-psychology

It is very common to think about how people think about you, how you look, how you sound, and how you can display your best towards others. But more often or not delving too much into these feeling and trying to act upon them can instead hurt you in the long run instead of helping you. Like for instance trying too hard to crack a joke only for it to fall face first into awkwardness, or trying too hard to get someone's attention only for you to make them feel uncomfortable.

**Question:**

At times with insecurities, even when though you know you have them, why is it so hard for some people to let go of their shortcomings?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Your example changes the context of the question. While the question asks about people trying to let go of *"their shortcomings"* and how people perceive others, your example questions how you can let go of a person. While it is only in there as an example, questions asking about how **you** can deal with a specific situation is off topic here and are closed for this reason. If you take your example out, the question is more general and can stand on its own.

Comment: I have edited your example out to help prevent question closure but feel free to edit it back in if you choose. However, in its form as it stood you may face question closure for personal advice sought.

Comment: This may be worth to read: [Why You Should Stop Caring What Other People Think (Taming the Mammoth) - Wait But Why](https://waitbutwhy.com/2014/06/taming-mammoth-let-peoples-opinions-run-life.html "Why You Should Stop Caring What Other People Think (Taming the Mammoth) - Wait But Why")